# Problem enabling PlotLegends in Mathematica 8.0

Tags: plotting, packages, version-8

I am trying to make a legend for a simple plot in *Mathematica* 8, but does not seem to recognise the command PlotLegends. I declared beforehand `` Needs["PlotLegends`"] ``, and get this message:

> Needs::nocont: Context PlotLegends` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>

I also tried to install this pakage manually by going to File -> Install -> ....
I am not very experienced with *Mathematica*, so an answer for dummies will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you have spelled the name of the package incorrectly. You get the same error message if you use a lowercase l or a double backtick quote instead of a single one.

Comment: Try in a "fresh" kernel.  First evaluate `Quit` to quit the kernel.  Then immediately, evaluate ``Needs["PlotLegends`"]``.    Do you still get this error message?  If yes, your Mathematica installation is either broken, or you have accidentally installed something named "PlotLegends" into your `$UserBaseDirectory` which is conflicting with loading the package that is bundled with Mathematica.  Evaluate `$UserBaseDirectory` to see where this location is, open it, and check that the `Applications` folder doesn't contain anything named PlotLegends.  If it doesn't then try reinstalling Mma.