# PlotLegend in Mathematica 8.0.4.0

Tags: plotting

We had to put Mathematica 8.0.4.0 on some Snow Leopard laptops we have at school (very outdated). I tried:

```
f[x_] := 3 x + 4
g[x_] := x
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -4, 4},
 PlotLegends -> {"f(x)", "g(x)"}]
```

But got:

Plot::optx: Unknown option PlotLegends in Plot[{f[x],g[x]},{x,-4,4},PlotLegends->{f(x),g(x)}]. >>

What did they do for plot legends back in the 8.0.4.0 day?

Comment: See the [PlotLegends Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage.html)

Comment: Try this? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33713/problem-enabling-plotlegends-in-mathematica-8-0 or try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522756/compatibility-of-plotlegend-with-mathematica-8

Comment: I would **never** use the `PlotLegends` package. That's why I wrote this answer here: [Creating legends for plots with multiple lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/245). I still use that code myself in version 8, too. If this works for you, I would suggest making this a duplicate. The syntax would be simply this: `autoLegend[Plot[{f[x],g[x]},{x,-4,4}],{"f(x)","g(x)"}]` (after executing the code cell in the link).

Comment: BTW, `autoLegend` still works in *Mathematica* 10.3 as well. So if you use it, you also get cross-version compatibility!

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the [PlotLegends package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html) and use the option [PlotLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/ref/PlotLegend.html) rather than `PlotLegends`

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];

f[x_] := 3 x + 4
g[x_] := x

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -4, 4}, PlotLegend -> {"f(x)", "g(x)"},
 LegendPosition -> {0.4, -0.7},
 LegendSize -> 0.5]
```

[image]